# Нарисуй-ка котёнка(,) на Боярского похожего

Tags: запятые

Где таки запятушонки нужны?

> 1. Нарисуй-ка котёнка(,) на Боярского похожего.

> 2. Какого котёнока мне нарисовать?

> Тебе надо котёнка(,) на Боярского похожего(,) нарисовать!

> Тебе надо котёнка нарисовать(,) на Боярского похожего!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все запятые нужны:

(1) *Нарисуй-ка котЁнка, **на БоЯрского похожего**.*

Какого котёнка мне нарисовать?

(2) *Тебе надо котЁнка, **на БоЯрского похожего**, нарисовАть!*

(3) *Тебе надо котЁнка нарисовать, **на БоЯрского похожего**!*

**Пояснение**

Во всех  случаях на определяемое слово падает **ударение,** а это условие **для обособления.** Оборот не обособляется, если ударение **переходит** на оборот, а на определяемом слове ударения нет.

**Инверсия** в структуре оборот ничего не меняет. В интерпозиции (вариант 2) оборот находится внутри **составного сказуемого** "надо нарисовать) и обособляется в любом случае.

Для сравнения:

*Котенка **на БоЯрского похожего** // тебе надо нарисовАть.*

Здесь ударение только на обороте. Это простое предложение.

Comment: Thanks, Leo. You understand this topic better than others. And you are on the way to success)